# Basic plane kinematics

Tags: 2d, physics, movement

I never did physics in my life and this is really hard for me. I am currently trying to implement movement in the X and Y axis of a plane, in a video game I am making.

What I want to do is, given a starting angle and a velocity, and the value of gravity, calculate in different points of time the current angle and the displacement in X and Y.

So, lets say, my current velocity is `4 units / second` and my current angle is `30 degrees` and my gravity is `9.8 u/s`, I want to pass an argument in seconds and calculate the final angle, velocity, and the amount of X and Y the body moved.

Comment: Gravity's acceleration is 9.8 u/s^2, sorry couldnt resist ;) Using a physics engine like bullet is not an option?

Comment: That would be useless, as I don't want to implement collisions and complicated movement. I am actually making a fan-made game of Super Mario 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the acceleration is constant, e.g. the only force acting on the body is gravitational, we can use a trivial expression for the displacement at any time. It is ***a*** integrated twice with respect to *t*. In vector form: ***x***(t) = **x**(0) + **v**(0) t + ½ **a** t².

The starting velocity can be derived from *θ* using: ***v*** = v (cos θ, sin θ) or a variant, depending on how the angle is defined.

With the example values of:

- ***x**(0) = (0, 0)*
- *v(0) = 4*
- *θ = 30°*
- ***a** = (0, -9.8)*

the displacement can be calculated as: ***x***(t) = (2√3, 2) t + (0,-4.9) t².

Answer (score 1):

Just do your math step by step (as long as you're not looking for complex simulation of this):

To move the plane based on its acceleration (`plane.a`; can be constant or `0`) you should first calculate its velocity along the axes:

```
plane.vx += plane.a * cos(plane.angle) * delta_time / 2.0;
plane.vy += plane.a * sin(plane.angle) * delta_time / 2.0;
```

This should get you some basic movement. Based on your coordinate system (e.g. in which direction the y coordinate becomes bigger) you might have to negate one or more parameters.

Once this is done, just apply the gravity as well:

```
plane.vy += gravity * delta_time / 2.0;
```

Then you can just update your coordinates:

```
plane.x += plane.vx * delta_time;
plane.y += plane.vy * delta_time;
```

If you're using fixed time steps in your logic, you can just assume `delta_time` being `1`, which makes the whole calculation even easier to be done. The velocities become simple deltas and your acceleration essentially becomes a constant velocity:

```
plane.x += plane.v * cos(plane.angle);
plane.y += plane.v * sin(plane.angle) + gravity;
```